# Javascript Alternative for Detecting Select Value Which Doesn't Use Xpath in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, xpath

I had a working solution to grab the value of a select using Xpath. Found out IE doesn't support Xpath  and it throws an "XpathResult is undefined" error!!! I'm using a TMS (DTM) so I have to inject my code into the web app. I can't touch the web app code. In researching this, I read that a library (https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) could fix this but I don't have that option. If you go to https://apply.essexcredit.com/ on the first page, you'll see only one select "What type of loan are you interested in? ". I need to set an event listener on this element and grab the value being selected (RV or Boat etc). Is there any other approach I can use to attach an event listener to this and grab the value? Here is the current code I had that works when Xpath is supported:

```
  function _dtmSetProductSel() {

    window.addEventListener("click", function() {

   var prodSel = document.evaluate("//form/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[@class='option-selected']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();

      if (prodSel) {
            var currProd = prodSel.getAttribute("title");

            if (currProd == "RV" || currProd == "Boat" || currProd == "Auto" || currProd == "Auto-IBG" || currProd == "Investment Line of Credit") {

                sessionStorage.setItem("_dtmSelProd", currProd);
            }

        } else {

            setTimeout(_dtmSetProductSel, 1000);
        }

    });

};
```

Comment: why can't you use `form div.option-selected` CSS to access the node?

Comment: Can you explain more about how that would be used? Not following? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can use `document.querySelector` as shown below.

```
var prodSelCSS = document.querySelector("form div.option-selected")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function _dtmSetProductSel() {
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var prodSel = document.getElementsByClassName("option-selected");
    var tryAgain = true;
    for(var i=0;i<prodSel.length;i++) {
        var currProd = prodSel[i].getAttribute("title");
        if(currProd && (currProd == "RV" || currProd == "Boat" || currProd == "Auto" || currProd == "Auto-IBG" || currProd == "Investment Line of Credit")) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("_dtmSelProd", currProd);
            tryAgain = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(tryAgain) {
        setTimeout(_dtmSetProductSel, 1000);
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.